# How to set listview items to right and left like conversation..?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Currently am developing an application for receiving messages and displaying them in the order which they came. But now am stuck at how to display these messages according to incoming and outgoing messages. I have a android phone with me.. In that messages are alligned to left and right.  I want to display messages just like that..?? I know that using listview i can do that but how...? any advise..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using relative layout and 
Consider two textViews in a layout and use them to inflate it to the list.
For these two textViews consider using

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

to one and

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

to another.

Comment: You should mention that this is possible using `Relative Layout` only. If OP is using `Linear Layout` that your answer will not work.

Comment: Can you once post the xml file you are using

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` using `BaseAdapter` and decide to display multiple rows with some logical condition. On the basis of View Type returned you can decide which view to display in List at which position. [`This blog`](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) has a complete explanation how ListView works using different views too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on G_S's answer and Android's simple_list_item_1.xml, here is some xml code for that problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```